# How to globally unescape content for Angular 5 binding

Tags: angular, rest, xss

**tl;dr;**
Is it possible to change angular's `{{ }}` binding behaviour so that it does not sanitize/escape values?

**Full question**
We have a fairly large angular 5 app backed by a json REST API. The REST API interfaces to a much larger system and database which has been established for many years. Other established applications read and write data and a key point is that user entered data from all apps must be stored verbatim in the database because other apps (legacy, non web apps) need to read and write the data.

This means that (whilst undesirable) the REST API supports POST's and PUT's with bodies like this:

```
{
  "reportName" : "<a href=\"http://somewhere.bad\">My report</a>",
  "reportType" : "VEHICLE"
}
```

(it needs to because the data needs to be written verbatim to the database so that other legacy non-web applications can read the data as entered by the user)

Currently the angular app is the only client of the REST API, but there are plans to expose the API such that other client code, including 3rd parties, can consume it.

At present, the REST API returns data in the form it was entered and persisted:

```
{
  "reportName" : "<a href=\"http://somewhere.bad\">My report</a>",
  "reportType" : "VEHICLE"
}
```

Conveniently the angular 5 app sanitizes or escapes (?) the values before rendering (binding?). The angular template binds the values like this:

```
<div>{{report.reportName}}</div>
```

so the onscreen output is:

```
<a href="http://somewhere.bad">My report</a>
```

which is the desired behaviour. (Forgive my undoubtably incorrect use of angular terminology - I'm more of a back-end dev!)

Unfortunately we've had an external penetration test of the REST API and they have unsurprisingly raised XSS type concerns, with their recommendation being that the REST API escapes content on the way out. Their argument is that security should not rely on the client. Whilst angular is santizing/escaping out of the box, other client code might not.
With this in mind, I've made a server side change so that json string values are escaped in response bodies:

```
{
  "reportName" : "&lt;a href=&quot;http://somewhere.bad&quot;&gt;My report&lt;/a&gt;",
  "reportType" : "VEHICLE"
}
```

But now of course, angular is sanitizing/escaping the ampersands, so onscreen it is rendered as:

```
&lt;a href=&quot;http://somewhere.bad&quot;&gt;My report&lt;/a&gt;
```

ie. the binding has effectively done:

```
<div>&amp;lt;a href=&amp;quot;http://somewhere.bad&amp;quot;&amp;gt;My report&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;</div>
```

What I think we need is for angular to trust the data in the response and render it verbatim. ie. if it interpolated rather than bound (again, forgive my terminology!), it would effectively do this:

```
<div>&lt;a href=&quot;http://somewhere.bad&quot;&gt;My report&lt;/a&gt;</div>
```

which would result in the onscreen rendering being

```
<a href="http://somewhere.bad">My report</a>
```

And this would be OK, because it's the current behaviour. It would not have been added to the DOM as a clickable or otherwise executable bit of markup - it's just text.

Is there a global way of telling angular 5 to treat values are being trusted? The problem we have of course is that as an already developed app of a reasonable size there are probably thousands of `{{ }}` style bindings in the templates, so rather than go through and change that syntax to something else (I've seen people doing things like `<div innerHTML="{{report.reportName}}"/>`, or using pipes like `<div>{{report.reportName | safeHtml}}</div>`) I'm looking for more of a global approach.

Any ideas?

Comment: You'll have to use a pipe, you can't change the behavior of all interpolation (`{{...}}`) at once. If you do, you'll have to change the framework itself.

Comment: I prefer the initial approach. Not escaping on the client can cause its own vulnerabilies. Now the security of the client depends on the server. If a client uses multiple APIs or changes from one to the other, then they can mix up whether to escape the data or not.

Comment: The server can't reliably escape the content because the correct escaping to use is context dependant. Something that's safe for a HTML context is not safe for a JS or CSS context. Any client that would have XSS issues because of this API probably has its own vulnerabilities that have nothing to do with it.